# Whats the best database and way to analyse time-series data changes

Tags: database-design

I started a project where I want to analyse data changes over time.
As an example this could be my model:

```
model TemperatureRecord{
lowest: float
highest: float
location: string
time: date
}
```

and I would create one per minute per location.

If this table is filled with data of a year and five locations i want to request all occurences (or simpler just the count of the occurences) where the lowest temperature of one record is more than 10 degrees below the record 5 minutes later.

I tried to achieve this with mysql and a join (with indexes on location and date) but it just takes to long for the request.

Is there a database made for this kind of analysis or a way to join the data more performant?

my current sql (used lag instead of join now):

```
with myItems as (
     Select Lag(lowest,5) over (PARTITION BY location ORDER BY time) as lowest,
   highest,time,location 
    from temperatures
    where location="one"
)
select time,location 
from myItems
where  lowest < highest-10
```

This takes about 20 seconds for 2 000 000 rows but i actually have about 40 000 000 rows and would like it to finish in less than 15 seconds

The indexes are on time and time+location. there also is a field id which is the primary column.

Explain analyze:

```
-> Filter: (myitems.lowest > (myitems.highest - 10))  (cost=0.34..367171.90 rows=1087801) (actual time=15906.430..16128.475 rows=5 loops=1)
    -> Table scan on myItems  (cost=2.50..2.50 rows=0) (actual time=15735.486..16016.583 rows=1741150 loops=1)
        -> Materialize CTE myitems  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=0) (actual time=15735.480..15735.480 rows=1741150 loops=1)
            -> Window aggregate with buffering: lag(temperatures.lowest,5) OVER (PARTITION BY temperatures.location ORDER BY temperatures.`time` )   (actual time=4604.195..15021.256 rows=1741150 loops=1)
                -> Sort: temperatures.location, temperatures.`time`  (cost=828644.80 rows=3263728) (actual time=3647.887..3726.757 rows=1741150 loops=1)
                    -> Index lookup on temperatures using IDX_f09fd9f9e9ec38cc56d9393f89 (location='one')  (cost=828644.80 rows=3263728) (actual time=0.677..3016.329 rows=1741150 loops=1)
```

Comment: For the amount of data your example discusses, that would only be about ~2.5 million rows, which is on the small side. Please update your Post and provide the query, indexes, and ideally the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`, as I'm sure MySQL (or any modern RDBMS) could handle your use cases easily.

Comment: You might want to look at using an in-memory database engine, instead. Take a look at https://www.timescale.com/